# DockPanel resizing items wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, dockpanel

I know there is a few examples out there but I would like to know if there is an alternative solution so here goes :).

I have a wpf applicaiton that is using a dockpanel and have labels displaying at the top as "headers". Everything is fine until I maximise the window. The labels don't resize, is there a way without using a grid to make this work? I tried using a grid but then it disables my ability to remove the items that are docked unfortunately :(. Any help would be great. I have also tried to use a grid splitter but had no success with that either

**Edit**

```
<Window x:Class="DockPanelTest.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="1500">

<Window.Resources>
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="headerBackground" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
        <GradientStop Color="#FFEFEEEE" Offset="0"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#E7E7E7E7" Offset="1"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="selectedHeaderBackground" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
        <GradientStop Color="#F6CD1D" Offset="0"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#EBA32A" Offset="1"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
</Window.Resources>
<DockPanel Name="myDockPanel">
        <Label Width="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="RockLabel" Content="Rock Properties" Margin="0,0,1,1" DockPanel.Dock="Left" Background="{StaticResource headerBackground}" VerticalAlignment="Top" MouseUp="RockLabel_MouseUp" />
        <Button Width="Auto" Name="CloseRock" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,1,1" Content="X" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="26" Background="{StaticResource headerBackground}" Click="CloseRock_Click" />
        <Label Width="Auto" Name="ContactsLabel" Margin="0,0,1,1" Content="Contacts" DockPanel.Dock="Left" Background="{StaticResource headerBackground}" VerticalAlignment="Top" MouseUp="ContactsLabel_MouseUp" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
        <Button Width="Auto" Name="CloseContacts" Margin="0,0,1,1" Content="X" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="26" Background="{StaticResource headerBackground}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Click="CloseContacts_Click" />
        <Label Width="Auto" Name="FluidLabel" Margin="0,0,1,1" Content="Fluid Properties" DockPanel.Dock="Left" Background="{StaticResource headerBackground}" VerticalAlignment="Top" MouseUp="FluidLabel_MouseUp" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
        <Button Width="Auto" Name="CloseFluid" Margin="0,0,1,1" Content="X" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="{StaticResource headerBackground}" Height="26" Click="CloseFluid_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
        <Label Width="Auto"  Name="RegionsLabel" Margin="0,0,1,1" Content="Regions" DockPanel.Dock="Left" Background="{StaticResource headerBackground}" VerticalAlignment="Top" MouseUp="RegionsLabel_MouseUp" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
        <Button Width="Auto" Name="CloseRegions" Margin="0,0,1,1" Content="X" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="{StaticResource headerBackground}" Height="26"  Click="CloseRegions_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
        <Label Width="Auto" Name="ProbabilitiesLabel" Margin="0,0,1,1" Content="Probabilities" DockPanel.Dock="Left" Background="{StaticResource headerBackground}" VerticalAlignment="Top" MouseUp="ProbabilitiesLabel_MouseUp" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
        <Button Width="Auto" Name="CloseProbabilities" Margin="0,0,1,1" Content="X" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="{StaticResource headerBackground}" Height="26" Click="CloseProbabilities_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
        <Label Width="Auto" Name="EconomicsLabel" Margin="0,0,1,1" Content="Economics" DockPanel.Dock="Left" Background="{StaticResource headerBackground}" VerticalAlignment="Top" MouseUp="EconomicsLabel_MouseUp"/>
        <Button Width="Auto" Name="CloseEconomics" Margin="0,0,1,1" Content="X" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="{StaticResource headerBackground}" Height="26" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Click="CloseEconomics_Click"/>
        <Button Width="Auto" Name="RestoreButton" Content="Restore" Height="32" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Click="RestoreButton_Click"/>
        <Button Width="Auto" Name="RestoreLabels" Content="Restore Labels" Height="32" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Click="RestoreLabels_Click"/>
</DockPanel>
```

**Edit**
[image]

What I want is for the label and button to fit the window even now as I increase the size of the window so the labels are across the window

Comment: It sounds like you want to maintain a layout as a window resizes. Can you give us more details about what that layout is? I disagree that using a `Grid` would stop you removing elements. Can you post some xaml that replicates the issue?

Comment: Yeah I can give you XAML and C# if you want? Maybe I'm doing it wrong trying to remove the elements but I gave it a go today and it didn't work for some reason

Comment: please provide a screenshot so we know what we're talking about

Comment: @Gusdor How would I go about using the grid then if I was to add one and still have the ability to delete the label, button and column for (e.g. rock properties)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand, there are your requirements:

- A layout that scales as a window resizes
- The ability to remove elements

This solution is a vast simplification but it should put you on the right track.

### XAML

```
<Window x:Class="ResizeSample.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ResizeSample"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid x:Name="Grid_ButtonHost">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Button Click="Button_Remove_Click">Click to remove</Button>
        <Button Click="Button_Remove_Click" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1">Click to remove</Button>
        <Button Click="Button_Remove_Click" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2">Click to remove</Button>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

### Code Behind

```
namespace ResizeSample
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Remove_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // we gave the hosting grid a name, so now we can remove the sender of the click event from the grid.
            // remember to cast the sender to UIElement!
            Grid_ButtonHost.Children.Remove((UIElement)sender);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah that's my requirements exactly, thanks for that, I'm presuming you can do the same to the grid columns in the code behind too?